# SHIM_NOVERSION_FOUND error while trying to run screensaver from preview

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, screensaver

I have an not trivial task to do. I need to run website as a screensaver in windows 8. So I used next approach to achieve it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31376/Making-a-C-screensaver

The solution is working well when I run from the Visual studio or run a compiled `.exe` or `.scr` directly. But when I try to set the resulting `.scr` as a screensaver and try to push preview button in windows 8(on the same machine where the same `.scr` is running well) I get the error - "SHIM_NOVERSION_FOUND".

I found that this error can appear when required version of .NET framework is not installed, but it's not my case cause when I run directly that '.scr' it's working.

Thanks for any advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved, I've just put `screensaver.scr` to `c:/temp` folder and all started working, probably I didn't have some kind of rights to access screensaver from c:/windows/system32